# Count values in overlapping sliding windows in python

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

Given an array, `a`, of *sorted* values, and an array of ranges, `bins`, what is the most efficient way to count how many values in `a` fall within each range, `rng`, in `bins`?

Currently I am doing the following:

```
def sliding_count(a, end, window, start=0, step=1):
    bins = [(x, x + window) for x in range(start, (end + 1) - window, step)]
    counts = np.zeros(len(bins))
    for i, rng in enumerate(bins):
        count = len(a[np.where(np.logical_and(a>=rng[0], a<=rng[1]))])
        counts[i] = count
    return counts

a = np.array([1, 5, 8, 11, 14, 19])
end = 20
window = 10
sliding_count(a, end, window)
```

Which returns the expected array

```
array([3., 4., 3., 3., 4., 4., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.])
```

But I feel like there must be a more effective way of doing this?

Comment: Imho this is quite effective. Do you look for a more efficient way?

Comment: did you know that `range` returns an object on which you can do `x in range(...)` and get a true/false?

Comment: @Nullman yes I did, but that would mean I would have to iterate `bins` once for each element in `a`

Comment: Will the window always be a multiple of the step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

def alt(a, end, window, start=0, step=1):
    bin_starts = np.arange(start, end+1-window, step)
    bin_ends = bin_starts + window
    last_index = np.searchsorted(a, bin_ends, side='right')
    first_index = np.searchsorted(a, bin_starts, side='left')
    return  last_index - first_index

def sliding_count(a, end, window, start=0, step=1):
    bins = [(x, x + window) for x in range(start, (end + 1) - window, step)]
    counts = np.zeros(len(bins))
    for i, rng in enumerate(bins):
        count = len(a[np.where(np.logical_and(a>=rng[0], a<=rng[1]))])
        counts[i] = count
    return counts

a = np.array([1, 5, 8, 11, 14, 19])
end = 20
window = 10

print(sliding_count(a, end, window))
# [3. 4. 3. 3. 4. 4. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]

print(alt(a, end, window))
# [3 4 3 3 4 4 3 3 3 3 3]
```

---

### How alt works:

Generate the starting and ending values of the bins:

```
In [73]: bin_starts = np.arange(start, end+1-window, step); bin_starts
Out[73]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])

In [74]: bin_ends = bin_starts + window; bin_ends
Out[74]: array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20])
```

Since `a` is in sorted order, you can use [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to find the first and last index
in `bin_starts` and `bin_ends` where each value in `a` fits:

```
In [75]: last_index = np.searchsorted(a, bin_ends, side='right'); last_index
Out[75]: array([3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6])

In [76]: first_index = np.searchsorted(a, bin_starts, side='left'); first_index
Out[76]: array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3])
```

The `count` is simply the difference in indices:

```
In [77]: last_index - first_index
Out[77]: array([3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3])
```

---

Here is a [perfplot](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot) comparing the performance of `alt` versus `sliding_count` as a function of the length of `a`:

```
import perfplot

def make_array(N):
    a = np.random.randint(10, size=N)
    a = a.cumsum()
    return a

def using_sliding(a):
    return sliding_count(a, end, window)

def using_alt(a):
    return alt(a, end, window)

perfplot.show(
    setup=make_array,
    kernels=[using_sliding, using_alt],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(22)],
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    xlabel='len(a)')
```

[image]

Perfplot also checks that the value returned by `using_sliding` equals the value returned by `using_alt`.

[Matt Timmermans' idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54237403/190597), "*subtract `position_in_a` from the count for that bin*" triggered this solution.

Answer (score 1):

The number of elements in a bin `b` is the number of elements `<= b.end` minus the number of elements `< b.start`.

So you can make a `starts` array of the bins sorted by start, and and `ends` array of bins sorted by end.  Then walk through all 3 arrays in step.  When you advance past each `x` in `a`, advance past the starts with `x < b.start` and *subtract* `position_in_a` from the count for that bin.  Then advance past the ends with `x <= b.end` and *add* `position_in_a` to the count for that bin.

Total complexity is O(N log N), dominated by sorting the start and end arrays.  Walking through the 3 arrays and adjusting the counts is O(N).

In your code you are *generating* the array of bins already sorted, so if you can do that then you can skip the sorting step and the total complexity is O(a.length+bin_count).  I would not bother even generating that array since you can easily calculate the start and end values from the index.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (?):

```
def sliding_count(a, nx0, nx1, window):
    bin0 = np.arange(nx0,nx1,1)
    bin1 = bin0 + window 
    count = np.zeros((nx1-nx0), dtype=int)

    for j in range(nx1-nx0):
        count[j] = np.sum(a<=bin1[j]) - np.sum(a<bin0[j])
    return count

#---- main ---------------  
nx0, nx1, window = 0, 11, 10
a = np.array([1, 5, 8, 11, 14, 19])
sliding_count(a, nx0, nx1, window)

array([3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3])
```

I did not check the code for *nx0>0* and *step>1* in *bin0 = np.arange(nx0,nx1,1)*. So the lenght of the for-loop has to be modified for such cases.